# Mathematical structuralism and Saussure

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, structuralism

Is mathematical structuralism related with structuralism that arose from Saussurean linguistics?

Comment: They aren't related

Comment: See [Mathematical Structuralism](https://www.iep.utm.edu/m-struct/).